# Prove for sequence $\lim_{n \to \infty} {\sqrt[n]{n^k} =1}\ \text{where}\ k\in\mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis

I have done the case that k=1... but got stuck when doing the case that k=2 and the induction(?) step...

My work on k=2

$\left.n^2=\left(\begin{array}{c}1+y_n\\\end{array}\right.\right)^n=1+ny_n+\frac{n\left(\begin{array}{c}n-1\\\end{array}\right)}{2}y_n^2+\cdots+y_n^n>1+\frac{n(n-1)\left(\begin{array}{c}n-2\\\end{array}\right)}{6}y_n^3$

but how to find N?

Comment: You might be overthinking it.. If you can prove that $x_n \to 1$, then what can you say about $x_n^2$?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. Hint: if $n^{k/n}=1+\epsilon_n$ then $\sqrt{n}=(1+\epsilon_n)^{n/(2k)}$ lets you bound $\epsilon_n$ with [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality).

Answer (score 1):

We know that $\begin{align} \lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{n}=1\end{align}$. We assume$\begin{align} \lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{n^k}=1\end{align}$. We prove by induction:
$\begin{align} \lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{n^{k+1}}= \lim_{n\to\infty} n^{\frac{k+1}{n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty} n^{\frac{k}{n}+\frac{1}{n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{n^k}\cdot\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n}=1\cdot1=1
 \end{align}$

Answer (score 0):

Let, $a_n=n^{k}$. Then, $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{(n+1)^k}{n^k}=\left( 1+\frac 1n\right)^k$. Then, for any $k\in \mathbb N$,
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=1.$$

By Cauchy's 2nd limit theorem, $\lim_{n \to \infty}(a_n)^{1/n}=1$.

Answer (score 0):

$\sqrt[n] {n^k} = n^{\frac{k}{n}}$. What happens to $\frac{k}{n}$ as $n \to \infty$

Answer (score 0):

$$
n^{k/n}=e^{\log n^{k/n}} = e^{\tfrac{k}{n}\log{n}}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}{(e^{0})^k}=1.
$$

If $k=1$ is known to be 1, then induction gives:
$n^{(k+1)/n} = n^{k/n}n^{1/n} = n^{k/n}\cdot n^{1/n} \xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty} 1.$